# Apply multiple filters to an image

Tags: android, android-gpuimageview

I am trying to apply 3 filters to an image.

One **rgbFilter** which is has its values constant, a **brightness filter** and a **saturation filter**.

Comment: Hi. Could you add a code snippet as to how you've solved this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use class:

> GPUImageFilterGroup

on the GPUImage Library.

It solves your problem.